# @Valid does not work in controller for DTO

Tags: java, spring, rest, controller, annotations

when sending an invalid request to http://localhost:8080/student, the annotation does not work and the invalid data goes further to the controller, service, etc.

```
import org.example.controller.dto.StudentDTO;
import org.example.service.interfaces.StudentService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.sql.SQLException;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class StudentController{
    private final StudentService service;
    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
    @PostMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<StudentDTO> doPost(@RequestBody @Valid StudentDTO studentDTO) {
            try {
                StudentDTO studentDTOOut = service.saveNewStudent(studentDTO);
                return new ResponseEntity<>( studentDTOOut, HttpStatus.OK);
                }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }
    }
```

DTO

```
public class StudentDTO {

    @NotNull
    private UUID id;

    @NotBlank
    private String surname;
//getters,setters
}
```

pom.xml

```
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.validation/jakarta.validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.24.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.214</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


   

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>
                            -Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorTimestamp=true
                        </arg>
                        <arg>
                            -Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorVersionInfoComment=true
                        </arg>
                        <arg>
                            -Amapstruct.verbose=true
                        </arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/org/example/service/DTO/mapper/**/*.class</exclude>
                                <exclude>
                                    **/target/generated-sources/annotations/org/example/service/DTO/mapper/**/*.class
                                </exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

postman
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKtNj.png)

I tried putting @Validated above the controller class, adding @JsonProperty(required = true) above the DTO fields. Delete produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE.
It doesn't work at all.

There is still a suspicion: should annotations @Validat @Validated work without spring boot?

Comment: import jakarta.validation.Valid (also import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull). Actually Spring 6 have upgraded to Jakarta EE 9+ : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Persistence

Comment: I tried this even before writing a question on the site. Jakarta or Javax don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Spring will automatically handle validation. Try to add `BindingResult` to your method. It will be populated with errors and you could handle them the way you want:

```java
public ResponseEntity<StudentDTO> doPost(@RequestBody @Valid StudentDTO studentDTO, BindingResult bindingResult) {

if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    List<String> errors = bindingResult.getFieldErrors().stream()
            .map(error -> error.getField() + " - " + error.getDefaultMessage()).toList();

    // do something
    }
}
```